# Insert data with php on server with cron(not working)

Tags: php, cron

On website i have php script with needs to be called in order to collect data and set to array from which it sends to mySql. I have tried cron job calling it with www.website.com/script/sc1.php?value="val" and the cron says it is done and ok, but it's not (the data is not inserted in mySql).

Is there any other way for me to do that or should i use task scheduler on windows or setup a program java or c++ to call the webpage in certain time (it's quite a bother so I would prefer an easier approach to the issue.

To recap: Cron is not working or rather wont execute the call (it's done in about 10-12sec due to high amount of data)
          Opening it in browser does work and it executes without issue.

I have tried using cron-job.org and the response i get for the call is:
[image]

[image]
[image]

Sorry for edits, the call is passed into switch statement and if val == any the proper function is called to insert data into mySql.

Comment: Show what you have entered in crontab for this script.
Usually cron calls php-cli which has much higher limits, so limiting the limit seems unlikely (though possible).
BTW setting these commands in the public directory is very bad practice.

Comment: www.website.com/scripts/sc1.php?value="val" it's sent with get command and those calls in folder are protected by password which is inserted in cron task. I set the call to get in cron as well. It shows its done and all ok but the data in mysql is not updated... I dont know if I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: Judging by the 2nd picture, you do not use cron but some application in the server's web panel. All you have to do is enter the control codes in you script that save the logs to the file (or email). Probably the variable val does not pass or there are a hundred other reasons in the code.

Comment: If I call it via browser (changing param) it executes and sends data ( tested with each call to print the call ). I'm not a "pro" when it comes to cron but I am unable to get it to do what I wrote in php. Hope I make sense... BTW thanks for your reply's

Comment: Is there a difference between browser call to http and cron's call? If there is can you point me to proper docs so I can look there. Thanks

Comment: But you enter .php[SPACE]from_value=val as in the picture into your browser? You can read about Crontab example here: <a href="https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/crontab.5.html">man crontab</a>

Comment: I'm not good with photo editing xD there is no space